# how to run my js file on server forever?

Tags: javascript, php, rss, client, server

I designed a site that gets news from another site's RSS and saves it to my DB. To do this I must send request to another site and save changes to my DB.
this is my code for sending request:

```
$q = $d->query("select * from site_setting where id=1");
$setting = $d->fetch($q);
$start = $setting['last'];
$q = $d->query("select *from newsagency order by id limit ".$start.",1");
while($agency = $d->fetch($q)){
    $url = $agency['link'];
    $size = 20;
    $agencyId = $agency['id'];
    $time = time();
    RSS_RetrieveLinks($url);
    if($size > 0)
        $recents = array_slice($RSS_Content, 0, $size + 1);
    $MaxTime = $d->getrowvalue("time","select `time` from news where agency={$agencyId} order by time  DESC limit 0,1",true);
    foreach($recents as $article)
    {
        $articleTime = strtotime($article["date"]);
        if($articleTime > ($MaxTime+1)){
            $d->iquery("news",array(
            'title'=>htmlspecialchars($article["title"]),
            'time'=>$articleTime,
            'link'=>$article["link"],
            'type'=>$article["type"],
            'img'=>$article["media"],
            'regTime'=>$time,
            'agency'=>$agencyId
            ));
            $return .= $article['title']."<br>";
        }       
    }
}
$last = $start +1;
$agencyCount = $d->getrowvalue("agenC","select count(id) as agenC from newsagency",true);
$agencyCount--;
if($last>$agencyCount) $last =  0;
$d->uquery("site_setting",array('last'=>($last)),"id=1");
```

this code gets rss link one by one from db and then gets data from rss and saves it to db, and everything in OK. to refresh the php page, we have a code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "load.php",
            context: document.body,
            success: function(vars){
                document.getElementById("imge").innerHTML+=vars;
            }
        })
    }, 500);
});
</script>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
<div id="imge"></p>
</body>
```

I refresh this code every 500 ms and get content from rss. The problem is that this page must forever be open and I don't have any idea to solve this problem. How can I send this request without getting the client's computer busy?

Comment: You want server-side scripting. You are doing client-side scripting. You *could* open a  web browser on the server and do the client-side scripting there, but it is better overall to do your server-side scripting in a server-side scripting language.

Comment: if you are running  centos on server, you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706625/bash-how-to-make-this-server-process-run-forever?rq=1. This will run your js file code forever.

Comment: Bear in mind that it's worth getting agreement to repeatedly fetch RSS feeds from another server. If you don't have that, they might block you, by referrer or by IP.